# Is java swing not working in java 8 update 45?

Tags: java, swing

The following code is working in jdk 1.8 update 45 and in java 1.8 update 31 but NOT in java 1.8 update 45.

The program is a button moving back and forth until the user presses the button and makes it stop and the text is changed to "MOVE". When the button is pressed again, the button starts moving and the text is changed to "STOP".

In java 8 update 45, the button does not start moving but the text changes. Why?

```
package mainpackage;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class mainPanel implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame1;
    JPanel panel1;
    JButton button = new JButton("STOP");

    boolean buttonPressed = false;
    boolean move = true;
    // 0 = left & 1 = right
    int direction = 1;
    int x = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new mainPanel().loadGUI();

}    

public void loadGUI() {
    frame1 = new JFrame("Moving button");
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    frame1.setSize(300, 58);
    frame1.setResizable(false);

    panel1 = new JPanel(); // Xwidth=294, Yheight=272
    panel1.setSize(300, 30);
    panel1.setLayout(null);
    frame1.add(panel1);

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame1.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame1.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame1.getSize().height/2);

    button.setSize(80, 30); //X, Y
    panel1.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(this);

    while(true) moveButton();


}


public void moveButton() {
    while(move == true) {
        switch(direction) {

            // left
            case 0: {
                while(x > 0) {
                    if(move == false) break;
                    button.setLocation(x, 0);
                    x--;
                    panel1.repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(mainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
                if(buttonPressed == true) {
                    direction = 0;
                    buttonPressed = false;
                } else if(buttonPressed == false) {
                    direction = 1;
                    buttonPressed = false;
                }
            }

            // right
            case 1: {
                while(x < panel1.getWidth() - button.getWidth()) {
                    if(move == false) break;
                    button.setLocation(x, 0);
                    x++;
                    panel1.repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(mainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
                if(buttonPressed == true) {
                    direction = 1;
                    buttonPressed=false;
                } else if(buttonPressed == false) {
                    direction=0; 
                    buttonPressed=false;
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (move == true){
        move=false;
    } else if (move == false) {
        move=true;
    }
    buttonPressed = true;
    if((button.getText()).equals("STOP")) {
        button.setText("MOVE");
    } else button.setText("STOP");
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by Java?  JRE?

Comment: `if (move == true){ move=false; } else if (move == false) { move=true; }` By the way, you can just write `move = !move;`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just added some methods and fixed some lines in your code, you can try it now:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class mainPanel implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame1;
    JPanel panel1;
    JButton button = new JButton("START");

    boolean buttonPressed = false;
    boolean move = false;
    Timer timer;
    int direction = 1;
    int x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new mainPanel().loadGUI();

    }

    public void loadGUI() {
        frame1 = new JFrame("Moving button");
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setSize(300, 58);
        frame1.setResizable(false);

        panel1 = new JPanel(); // Xwidth=294, Yheight=272
        panel1.setSize(300, 30);
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        frame1.add(panel1);

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame1.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - frame1.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - frame1.getSize().height / 2);

        button.setSize(80, 30); //X, Y
        panel1.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        moveButton();

    }

    public void moveButton() {
        if (timer == null) {
            initTimer();
        }
        move = !move;
        if (move) {
            button.setText("STOP");
            direction = (direction == 0) ? 1 : 0;
            timer.start();
        } else {
            button.setText("MOVE");
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    public void initTimer() {
        timer = new Timer(10, (e) -> {
            switch (direction) {
                case 0: // right
                    x++;
                    if (x >= panel1.getWidth() - button.getWidth()) {
                        direction = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1: // left
                    x--;
                    if (x <= 0) {
                        direction = 0;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            button.setLocation(x, 0);
            panel1.repaint();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        moveButton();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good and I like it. Only two problems: the buttons changes direction when pressed and formatting I am not used to (and do not understand), "(10, (e) ->".

Comment: I thought you want it to change the direction everytime you press it, if not just remove direction = (direction == 0) ? 1 : 0; in moveButton() 
and (e)-> is lambda check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html
I can remove it if you want but you said you are using java 8 so i was like why not using lambda

Comment: Now it works just as I wanted it too! And it is really similar to my original code, making it easy for me to understand. And thanks the lambda tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

Yours is broken code to begin with since it ignores Swing threading rules, and frankly I'm surprised that it worked in previous versions of Java. You're calling a `while (true)` loop that will tie up any thread that it is called in. Java 8 is correctly trying to start your Swing GUI on the Swing event thread, something that all Swing programs should do. If you get rid of the `while (true)` loops that risk being called on the Swing event dispatch thread, and instead use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) your code should work. The Timer will run a loop in a background thread, but all code called repeatedly in its ActionListener will be called on the Swing event thread.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyMainPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 300;
   private static final int PREF_H = 30;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;
   public static final int DELTA_X = 3;
   private JButton moveButton = new JButton(new MoveButtonAction("Move"));
   private Timer moveTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new MoveTimerListener());
   private boolean moveRight = true;

   public MyMainPanel() {
      moveButton.setSize(moveButton.getPreferredSize());

      int y = (getPreferredSize().height - moveButton.getPreferredSize().height) / 2;
      moveButton.setLocation(0, y);

      setLayout(null); // !! lord I hate this
      add(moveButton);

      moveTimer.start();
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return superSz;
      }
      int prefW = Math.max(superSz.width, PREF_W);
      int prefH = Math.max(superSz.height, PREF_H);
      return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
   }

   private class MoveButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
      public MoveButtonAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         moveRight = !moveRight;
      }
   }

   private class MoveTimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (moveRight) {
            if (moveButton.getLocation().x + moveButton.getWidth() >= getWidth()) {
               moveRight = false;
            }
         } else {
            if (moveButton.getLocation().x <= 0) {
               moveRight = true;
            }
         }
         int x = moveButton.getLocation().x + (moveRight ? DELTA_X : -DELTA_X);
         int y = moveButton.getLocation().y;
         moveButton.setLocation(new Point(x, y));
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      MyMainPanel mainPanel = new MyMainPanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Example");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

You will want to read up on Swing thread safety to see why your program is failing. See [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to see more on this.

---

**Edit:** code that stops and starts movement:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyMainPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final String MOVE = "Move";
   private static final String STOP = "Stop";
   private static final int PREF_W = 300;
   private static final int PREF_H = 30;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;
   public static final int DELTA_X = 3;
   private MoveButtonAction moveButtonAction = new MoveButtonAction(STOP);
   private JButton moveButton = new JButton(moveButtonAction);
   private Timer moveTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new MoveTimerListener());
   private boolean moveRight = true;

   public MyMainPanel() {
      moveButton.setSize(moveButton.getPreferredSize());

      int y = (getPreferredSize().height - moveButton.getPreferredSize().height) / 2;
      moveButton.setLocation(0, y);

      setLayout(null); // !! lord I hate this
      add(moveButton);

      moveTimer.start();
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return superSz;
      }
      int prefW = Math.max(superSz.width, PREF_W);
      int prefH = Math.max(superSz.height, PREF_H);
      return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
   }

   private class MoveButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
      public MoveButtonAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (MOVE.equals(getValue(NAME))) {
            moveTimer.start();
            putValue(NAME, STOP);
            int mnemonic = (int) STOP.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
         } else {
            moveTimer.stop();
            putValue(NAME, MOVE);
            int mnemonic = (int) MOVE.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
         }
         AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();
         button.setSize(button.getPreferredSize());
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private class MoveTimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (moveRight) {
            if (moveButton.getLocation().x + moveButton.getWidth() >= getWidth()) {
               moveRight = false;
            }
         } else {
            if (moveButton.getLocation().x <= 0) {
               moveRight = true;
            }
         }
         int x = moveButton.getLocation().x + (moveRight ? DELTA_X : -DELTA_X);
         int y = moveButton.getLocation().y;
         moveButton.setLocation(new Point(x, y));
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      MyMainPanel mainPanel = new MyMainPanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Example");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: One of the worst things about breaking threading rules is that the system can sucker you into thinking the code is OK by letting it work for a while, and then break at some inconvenient time.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: yep, and it usually fails when you're demo'ing your great program for your boss, coworkers or friends.

Comment: It probably worked because `setLocation` happens to be done under tree lock. But if so, it's entirely circumstantial and @PatriciaShanahan's comment is exactly what is going on. The code is generally not thread-safe.

Comment: @uranibaba: yes, and that you read up on Swing thread safety to see why your program is failing. See [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to see more on this. Also see example timer program above.

Comment: Removed my comment, I did not see this not being the original post and thus missed the suggested code using timer.

Comment: This does what I wanted but it is above my level. The purpose of the code was practice and even though your code works, I cannot read all of it. But I am going to take some pieces from it, like how you fixed the size of the frame and the button. A big thanks!
PS. The reason why I did setLayout(null) is because I wanted to be able to set the location of the button freely. I did not manage to do that with layouts.